# How to use reveal_type in mypy

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have read that I can reveal the type of variables by using a function called `reveal_type`, but I can't find how to use it or from where to import it.

Comment: Also see: https://sobolevn.me/2019/08/testing-mypy-types

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I found out in the end how to use it: You should just put and use the `reveal_type` in the code, and run it with the `mypy` program. Then, it will log a message that look like this:

```
Revealed type is 'builtins.str*'
```

From the `mypy` documentation:

> reveal_type is only understood by mypy and doesn’t exist in Python, if you try to run your program. You’ll have to remove any reveal_type calls before you can run your code. reveal_type is always available and you don’t need to import it.

For more reading: [here](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html?highlight=reveal_type#reveal-type).

Answer (score 2):

To add to [the current answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44625435/5694144), you can use the `TYPE_CHECKING` flag from `typing` to have Python skip code that is only for mypy, or to have mypy skip code you don't want it to check.

```py
# myfile.py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING


a = 'spam' and 5
print(a)

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type(a)  # python skips this line
else:
    a = 1/2  # mypy can't see this type error
print(a)
```

```
❯ python3 myfile.py 
5
0.5

❯ mypy myfile.py 
myfile.py:8: note: Revealed type is "Union[builtins.str, builtins.int]"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Answer (score 1):

### TLDR

Just put `reveal_type(var)` in the code and run a type checker such as mypy.

### Python 3.11+

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.reveal_type):

> `typing.reveal_type(obj, /)`
>
> Ask a static type checker to reveal the inferred type of an expression.
>
> [...]
>
> At runtime, this function prints the runtime type of its argument to
> sys.stderr and returns the argument unchanged (allowing the call to be
> used within an expression):

Example:

*test.py*

```
from typing import reveal_type

a = 15
b = 7.2

c = reveal_type(a) + b
reveal_type(c)
```

Output of the most popular type checker MyPy:

```
$ mypy .
test.py:6: note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
test.py:7: note: Revealed type is "builtins.float"
```

Output of Python 3.11:

```
$ python test.py
Runtime type is 'int'
Runtime type is 'float'
```

### older Python versions

There is a backport of this feature: `from typing_extensions import reveal_type`

### MyPy only

If you do not run the code with Python (i.e. you just insert `reveal_type` briefly for debugging), **you can skip the import statement**. MyPy doesn't require it (unless you use the option `--enable-error-code unimported-reveal` - see [MyPy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/error_code_list2.html#check-that-reveal-type-is-imported-from-typing-or-typing-extensions-unimported-reveal)).