# Difference between Python type hints of type and Type?

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting, python-typing

Today, I came across a function type hinted with `type`.

I have done some research as to when one should type hint with `type` or `Type`, and I can't find a satisfactory answer.  From my research it seems there's some overlap between the two.

My question:

- What is the difference between `type` and `Type`?
- What is an example use case that shows when to use `type` vs `Type`?

---

**Research**

Looking at the source for [`Type` (from `typing` tag `3.7.4.3`)](https://github.com/python/typing/blob/3.7.4.3/src/typing.py#L2096), I can see this:

> ````py
> # Internal type variable used for Type[].
> CT_co = TypeVar('CT_co', covariant=True, bound=type)
>
>
> # This is not a real generic class.  Don't use outside annotations. 
> class Type(Generic[CT_co], extra=type):
>     """A special construct usable to annotate class objects. ```
> ````

It looks like `Type` may just be an alias for `type`, except it supports `Generic` parameterization.  Is this correct?

---

**Example**

Here is some sample code made using `Python==3.8.5` and `mypy==0.782`:

```py
from typing import Type

def foo(val: type) -> None:
    reveal_type(val)  # mypy output: Revealed type is 'builtins.type'

def bar(val: Type) -> None:
    reveal_type(val)  # mypy output: Revealed type is 'Type[Any]'

class Baz:
    pass

foo(type(bool))
foo(Baz)
foo(Baz())  # error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "Baz"; expected "type"
bar(type(bool))
bar(Baz)
bar(Baz())  # error: Argument 1 to "bar" has incompatible type "Baz"; expected "Type[Any]"
```

Clearly `mypy` recognizes a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`type` is a metaclass.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python) Just like object instances are instances of classes, classes are instances of metaclasses.

`Type` is an annotation used to tell a type checker that a class object itself is to be handled at wherever the annotation is used, instead of an instance of that class object.

There's a couple ways they are related.

1. The annotated return type when `type` is applied to an argument is `Type`. This is in the same way that `list` applied to an argument (like `list((1, 2))`) has an annotated returned type of `List`. Using [reveal_type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44625422/how-to-use-reveal-type-in-mypy) in:

```
reveal_type(type(1))
```

we are asking what is the inferred type annotation for the return value of `type` when it is given 1. The answer is `Type`, more specifically `Type[Literal[1]]`.

2. `Type` a type-check-time construct, `type` is a runtime construct. This has various implications I'll explain later.

Moving onto your examples, in:

```
class Type(Generic[CT_co], extra=type):
    ...
```

We are not annotating `extra` as `type`, we are instead passing the keyword-argument `extra` with value `type` to the metaclass of `Type`. See [Class-level Keyword Arguments](http://martyalchin.com/2011/jan/20/class-level-keyword-arguments/) for more examples of this construct. Note that `extra=type` is *very different* from `extra: type`: one is assigning a value at runtime, and one is annotating with a type hint at type-check time.

Now for the interesting part: if `mypy` is able to do successful type checking with both, why use one over the other? The answer lies in that `Type`, being a type-check time construct, is much more well integrated with the typing ecosystem. Given this example:

```
from typing import Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

def smart(t: Type[T], v: T) -> T:
    return v

def naive(t: type, v: T) -> T:
    return v

v1: int = smart(int, 1) # Success.
v2: int = smart(str, 1) # Error.

v3: int = naive(int, 1) # Success.
v4: int = naive(str, 1) # Success.
```

`v1`, `v3` and `v4` type-check successfully. You can see that `v4` from `naive` was a false positive, given that the type of `1` is `int`, not `str`. But because you cannot parametrized the `type` metaclass (it is not `Generic`), we're unable to get the safety that we have with `smart`.

I consider this to be more of a language limitation. You can see [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/#parameters-to-generics-are-available-at-runtime) which is attempting to bridge the same kind of gap, but for `list` / `List`. At the end of the day though, the idea is still the same: the lowercase version is the runtime class, the uppercase version is the type annotation. Both can overlap, but there are features exclusive to both.

Comment: Wow this answer has given me lots to learn about. Thank you @MarioIshac!   If you keep posting answers like this, I think you'll have tons of reputation in no time

Answer (score 3):

Since Python 3.9, they are the same and `typing.Type` is deprecated. Quoting [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type):

> deprecated since version 3.9: builtins.type now supports subscripting ([]). See [PEP 585](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/) and [Generic Alias Type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-genericalias).

[Mario Ishac's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64107045/9681081) is correct for earlier versions though.